# How to setup precompiled jsps with Tomee/Openejb?

Tags: openejb, apache-tomee

I am having this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to load servlet class: org.apache.jsp.versionMessage_jsp: org.apache.jsp.versionMessage_jsp
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:1924)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$ProcessAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:1691)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:336)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:363)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:850)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:881)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.versionMessage_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:94)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:67)
```

This the setup: 
1. versionMessage.jsp is precompiled via org.apache.jasper.JspC 
2. web.xml is declaration is as follows:

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.versionMessage_jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.versionMessage_jsp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.versionMessage_jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/versionMessage.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

1. If I don' precompile, just raw jsp is included in the war, there is no problem.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer in the openejb user forum [here](http://openejb.979440.n4.nabble.com/Tomee-Openejb-can-t-seem-to-find-jsp-precompiled-servlet-class-td4660481.html#a4660528)